# Need to expose HTTP API from aws kinesis stream, all serverless, what is the best option?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Need to expose HTTP API from aws kinesis stream, all serverless, what is the best option to do it serverless?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon API Gateway. You can create a Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream to an HTTP endpoint, which eliminates the need to develop custom applications or manage the corresponding infrastructure.

Please refer to the blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/stream-data-to-an-http-endpoint-with-amazon-kinesis-data-firehose/) for details.